# Angular expressions evaluating against constants

Tags: javascript, angularjs, performance, angularjs-scope

If I have `$scope.FOO_CONST = 4` then I can do:

```
<div ng-show="bar.status == FOO_CONST">I'm in the FOO state</div>
```

But if I'm understanding correctly, that creates a watcher function that will be evaluated each digest cycle for changes both in `bar.status` and for changes in `FOO_CONST`, even though I know the latter will never change. <s>So if I have:</s>

```
<div ng-show="bar.status == ::FOO_CONST">I'm in the FOO state</div>
```

Is that redundant check on FOO_CONST removed? And if so, is that more performant? (I've been finding that with large angular apps performance is something to think about as I go..)

Alternatively, is there a better way to achieve testing against constants in angular expressions?

UPDATE: turns out that the `== ::FOO_CONST` is not valid syntax in 1.3.5. So I'll change my question to:

What's the performant way to  have an angular expression evaluate a variable against a constant? (i.e. only watch for changes on one side of the test)

Answer (score 1):

The watch is actually set on the expression, not the individual variables.  Each digest, angular will evaluate the expression:

```
bar.status == FOO_CONST
```

and compare it to the previous value.  If it has changed it will trigger the watch function.

So only one $watch is created, and you are doing it in the most performant way possible.

EDIT:

If you bar.status can have several possible values, and if you have several sections each doing

```
"bar.status ==  SOME_CONSTANT"
```

then ng-switch would definitely help reduce the number of watches.

```
<div ng-switch="bar.status">
    <div ng-switch-when="FOO_CONST">
    </div>
    <div ng-switch-when="FOO_CONST1">
    </div>
    <div ng-switch-when="FOO_CONST2">
    </div>
<div>
```

has only one watch (on the expression "bar.status") vs. three watches if you use the currently inferred implementation.

Comment: Technically you could evaluate that expression to a single boolean whenever `bar.status` changes. It would just watch that one $scope property instead. It wouldn't offer much of a performance difference though. Probably barely measurable.